# On creation annihilation operators of the free Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, vacuum, klein-gordon-equation

I want to calculate multiparticle states like $|\vec p,\vec p\rangle$ from $|0\rangle$. It seems that I would need to compute from things like: $a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}|0\rangle$?

It seems to me that the first should yield a multiparticle state such as $|\vec p,\vec p\rangle$, i.e. two bosons in the mode $E_p$, however, shouldn't it be the case that $[a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}, a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}]=0$, in which case we simply get $0$ instead of the desired multiparticle state. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: $|\vec{p}, \vec{p} \rangle - |\vec{p}, \vec{p}\rangle =0$. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Hyperon I am asking how to calculate $|\vec p, \vec p\rangle$ from $|0\rangle$; where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that that commutator being zero means that that state is equal to zero? That commutator doesn't show up in the expression for that state. (Also, as a side note, we don't write down the state as $\lvert \vec{p}\vec{p}\rangle$. Rather, it's written as $\lvert 2_{\vec{p}}\rangle$, or something similar, to indicate that there are two particles occupying the single particle $\vec{p}$-state. You're mixing the "first quantized" and "second quantized" notations.)

Comment: @march Thanks, for this tip. The notation you are using is the "occupancy" basis, correct? I didn't realize that this is the only way to write multiparticle states.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus The idea behind the occupation-number representation is that it, along with the bosonic commutation relations, guarantees symmetry of the wave function under particle-exchange. The "wave function" $|vec{p},\vec{p}\rangle$ is symmetric, so it's perfectly fine, and it corresponds to the state $|2_{\vec{p}}\rangle$. However, if you had two different momenta, i.e., $|1_{p}1{q}\rangle$, this corresponds to the "wave function" $(|pq\rangle + |qp\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. The question still remains as to why you think the commutator being zero implies that the state is zero.

Comment: @march I will add those details to my post.

Comment: Why is your focus on a state in which both particles have the same momentum?

Answer (score 2):

$[a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}, a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}]=0$ holds for any bosonic operator. It does **not** imply that $a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p} = 0$, because $[a^{\dagger}_{\vec p},a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}] = a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p} - a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}$. Notice that, for example, $[\mathbb{1},\mathbb{1}] = 0$, but $\mathbb{1} \neq 0$.Your original assumption is correct: $|\vec{p}\vec{p}\rangle = a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p} |0\rangle \neq 0$.

Comment: It seems to me the question is ill-defined. First, one must define what is meant by $|p,p\rangle$; else the question really makes no sense and equations like $|p,p\rangle=a^\dagger_p a^\dagger_p|0\rangle$ are only hollow words.

Comment: @TobiasFünke This answer is responsive to OP's question: *"[S]houldn't it be the case that $[a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}, a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}]=0$, in which case we simply get $0$ instead of the desired multiparticle state."* The short answer is "no." This answer explains why the answer is no... I.e., the commutator being zero doesn't imply that he commuting objects are identically zero.

Comment: However, there are many different ways to define $|\vec p, \vec p\rangle$, the differences mainly being normalization factors, like $\sqrt{2\omega_p}$. So, while it would be good for OP to add more details, at least part of OP's question can be answered.

Comment: By $|\vec p,\vec p\rangle$ I mean a two particle state created by the action of the creation operator on $|0\rangle$. Basically two particles with identical momentum.  I bring up the commutator because I wanted to find $a^{\dagger}_{\vec p} |\vec p\rangle=a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}|0\rangle$. If it were $a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}^{\prime} |\vec p\rangle =a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}^{\prime} a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}|0\rangle$ then I could use the commutation relation to evaluate in the usual way.

Comment: That's the point: There is nothing to do, nothing to calculate. But yes, this answer points out a flaw in OPs line of reasoning.